# Azure DevOps Pipeline Self-Hosted Agent (Windows) can't launch Docker due to unescaped backslashes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've installed the Azure DevOps agent on my Windows 10 system.  When attempting to run my pipeline it fails to run the launch_docker.sh script on the agent, seemingly because backslashes in the path to the script have not been escaped.

Is there a way to configure the agent or pipeline to escape backslashes?

Alternatively, is there a way to run AzureStaticWebApp@0 task without bash/WSL/Docker?  I was surprised that it needed this since it is not mentioned anywhere in the agent setup instructions.

Pipeline log:

[image: Pipeline task error log]

Pipeline definition:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: Default

steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    app_location: /
    output_location: /output
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-static-web-app-v0?view=azure-pipelines).

> Note This task only runs on Linux agents.